# Can linear regression be done on PCA output in WEKA

Tags: weka, linear-regression, pca

If I am doing attribute selection via PCA using Ranker, after I get the output how can i perform Linear regression on it? Is it posible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `AttributeSelectedClassifier` (located in the meta section). There you should configure the `evaluator` and the `search` algorithms to `PrincipalComponents` and `Ranker` and the `classifier` to `LinearRegression`.

Another option is to apply a `PrincipalComponents` filter on the data.

Comment: That was helpful. How can LinearRegression applied on the results of Principal components?